# Make Bootstrap navbar brand on its own row resizable with images

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I found a way online to make a Bootstrap navbar on two rows, with the `navbar-brand` on its own row:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-column align-items-stretch">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-sm-auto mr-auto text-dark">My website</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarContent">
      <div class="navbar-nav nav-fill px-lg-5 mx-lg-5">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

(It collapses on small screens, so view as a full page to see it in action)

Now that I got that working, there are two things that I want to accomplish:

1. Have two scalable images flanking the navbar-brand (on either side of it). They should be as tall as the navbar-brand is (plus maybe a little margin up and down)
2. Have the text of the navbar-brand scale with the size of the window. I would set a max size (like font-size: 300%), but it should scale as the window width shrinks

What I have so far is responsive font-sizes for the different window widths using bootstrap breakpoints (see below, although for some reason it's not working in the code snippet. Perhaps because I'm overriding bootstrap code. Or perhaps SO code snippets don't allow SASS includes...)

It would be nicer if it would gradually scale, instead of just at the above breakpoints. Also, I'm not sure how to do this with images, so that they're at the same height as the text. How do I do this? I'm not so familiar with flexboxes, which is how this two-row navbar seems to be implemented. I tried looking into it, but I'm getting confused. Right now all I can figure to do is have a set height for the images.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 100%
}

.navbar img {
    height: 100px;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {  
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 250%;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light flex-column align-items-stretch">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-sm-auto mr-auto text-dark">My website</a>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarContent">
      <div class="navbar-nav nav-fill px-lg-5 mx-lg-5">
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ">Link here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding your logo-text with 2 images can be done simply by adding them into the ancher tag like so:

```
<a href="#"> <img src=""> Logo-text <img src=""> </a>
```

If your navbar has a height set you can make your img responsive ( scalable ) with this code:

```
a img { width: auto; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: I'll add images to show what I'm trying to do. Your breakpoints suggestion is what I'm already doing, so this is more of a comment than an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes i see now you allready have the code. Your question is a bit confusing since you allready have the answer on your own first question.

I will edit the code to give answer to your first question.

Comment: I wasn't asking how to add images or how to style them. I was asking how to make them scale with the navbar-brand.

Comment: @robev is this what you where looking for? ( i edited the answer )

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I edited the question to clarify your questions. With regards to your answer, you wrote "if your navbar has a height set". It doesn't, and that's part of my question. The row with the navbar-brand scales depending on the font size, which depends on the screen width.

Comment: Is there a reason you dont want to set a fixed height? You can still scale everything accordingly even the fixed height with the breakpoint..

Comment: It's not ideal that I have to make a dozen breakpoints instead of it scaling itself depending on the size of the screen.